# MVC 4 | Kendo UI | Dropdownlist Change event

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I have KendoUI Dropdownlist placed inside the Kendo Grid and i am able to set the change event on the dropdown list using the code below

```
function onDropDownChanged(e) {    
        var text = $("#TestMethodId").data("kendoDropDownList").value();
        alert(text);    
    }
```

using the code above 
1. how would i be able to access the ViewBag content like 'ViewBag.Test'?
2. I need to iterate through the values inside the ViewBag and set one of the textbox property in the grid to the value from that viewbag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is: **you can't**. You are trying to mix client-side processing with server-side processing. This is simply not possible.

The `onDropDownChanged` function will execute after an action preformed by the user. This means that the Razor engine has already parsed the `.cshtml` files and sent the HTML code to the client. This in turn means that any instruction containing the `ViewBag` object has already been executed.

Now, I don't really know what your `ViewBag` contains. Therefore, I'll make the assumption that you have stored some `string`s (values) and that the property names are stored as options in the `dropdownlist`. You probably want to access the data in the `ViewBag`, based on what you select in the `dropdownlist`. In that case, you should do the following:

1. In your controller, create a dictionary with the keys being the values of your `dropdownlist` and the values, whatever you need; save this dictionary in the `ViewBag`
2. In your view, convert the dictionary to a JSON string, and parse it client side to get an object with the same keys
3. In the `onDropDownChanged` event, just access this object using the select `text` to get the desired value.

Your question is a bit vague, therefore I cannot be 100% certain that this is what you need. The bottom line is, you can't mix server-side and client-side code in that way. You need to rely on tricks.

EDIT:
Here is a trick that could help you. In your view, serialize the `ViewBag` and save the value to a JavaScript variable; parse the text into an object; you can now iterate it using JavaScript.

```
<script>
     var tmpViewBag = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.MyObject))'; //notice I'm using ' and not "
     var myOptions = [];

     $(document).ready(function() {
          myOptions = JSON.parse(tmpViewBag); //you now have the object array
     })
</script>
```

Inside the select event you can now use the object array as follows:

```
function onDropDownChanged(e) {    
    var text = $("#TestMethodId").data("kendoDropDownList").value();
    //alert(text);    

    for (var i = 0; i < myOptions.length; i++) {
        if (myOptions.TestName === text) { //it can as well be ".TestId"
            $("#mytextbox").value(myOptions.PassThreshold); //you can set whatever you want
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you then suggest an alternative for this.
As my viewbag will persist the data in it. On selection change i just need to iterate through the viewbag content and populate the textbox value.

Comment: @SantoshNavle, as I wrote in my answer, you can create a dictionary with all the possible values. This, of course, works only if you have a reasonably small list of values. Convert this dictionary into a JavaScript object. This object can then be iterated (or directly) accessed using the value of the dropdown.

Comment: The viewbag that is serialized has the below values

[{"TestId":1,"TestName":"Marker","PassThreshold":4,"FailThreshold":4},{"TestId":2,"TestName":"ABC","PassThreshold":5,"FailThreshold":5},{"TestId":3,"TestName":"VI","PassThreshold":6,"FailThreshold":6}]

Now when a drop down value is selected say '1'
I need to get the Pass threshold value for TestId = 1 (selected drop down value) and display it on the text box (say 4) in the grid.

Hope now it is clearly understood.

Comment: @SantoshNavle, based on the values you provided, I updated the answer.